# Multiple insert overwrite into multiple tables query stores same results in all temp tables

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am doing a query with multiple INSERT OVERWRITE to multiple tables, in order to scan the
dataset only 1 time, and i end up having all these tables with the same content ! It seems
the GROUP BY query that returns results is overwriting all the temp tables.

This is the misbehaving query:

```
FROM nikon
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE e1
SELECT qs_cs_s_aid AS Emplacements, COUNT(*) AS Impressions
WHERE qs_cs_s_cat='PRINT' GROUP BY qs_cs_s_aid
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE e2
SELECT qs_cs_s_aid AS Emplacements, COUNT(*) AS Vues
WHERE qs_cs_s_cat='VIEW' GROUP BY qs_cs_s_aid
;
```

It launches only one MR job and here are the results. Why does table 'e1' contains results
from table 'e2' ?! Table 'e1' should have been empty (see individual SELECTs further below)

```
hive> SELECT * from e1;
OK
NULL    2
1627575 25
1627576 70
1690950 22
1690952 42
1696705 199
1696706 66
1696730 229
1696759 85
1696893 218
Time taken: 0.229 seconds

hive> SELECT * from e2;
OK
NULL    2
1627575 25
1627576 70
1690950 22
1690952 42
1696705 199
1696706 66
1696730 229
1696759 85
1696893 218
Time taken: 0.11 seconds
```

Here is are the result to the indiviual queries (only the second query returns a result set):

```
hive> SELECT qs_cs_s_aid AS Emplacements, COUNT(*) AS Impressions FROM nikon
WHERE qs_cs_s_cat='PRINT' GROUP BY qs_cs_s_aid;
(...)
OK
      <- There are no results, this is normal
Time taken: 41.471 seconds

hive> SELECT qs_cs_s_aid AS Emplacements, COUNT(*) AS Vues FROM nikon
WHERE qs_cs_s_cat='VIEW' GROUP BY qs_cs_s_aid;
(...)
OK
NULL  2
1627575 25
1627576 70
1690950 22
1690952 42
1696705 199
1696706 66
1696730 229
1696759 85
1696893 218
Time taken: 39.607 seconds
```

Comment: Maybe it's caused by [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2750). Are you using Hive 0.9 ?

Comment: Yes, using Cloudera 4.1 Hive 0.9 hive-0.9.0+150-1.cdh4.1.1.p0.4.el6.noarch

Comment: What's weird and which i noticed afterwards, is that if i take this same set of requests, and add more group by requests with same of different field, then temp table is populated correctly, even the temp tables that would have been badly overwritten

Comment: I created [HIVE-3699](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-36990)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jira issue i created HIVE-3699 has been fixed. Patches are available there, and should be merged with hive-0.11. Cloudera 4.2-rc has the patch included